# Gravitational forces of a building

Tags: newtonian-gravity, reference-frames, mass, statics, building-physics

In trying to understand the gravitational forces of a building, I have devised a thought experiment:

A building is floating in space. The building's mass is asymmetrically distributed. Inside it also has a large concentrated mass, not aligned to the center of gravity of the building as a whole.

We let loose a bunch of dust particles inside the building. Given the gravitational forces of the building's mass, where would these particles be collected?

I have considered a couple of scenarios:

A: The dust would float around evenly distributed, because the gravitational forces inside the building cancel each other out.

B: The dust collect around its nearest walls and ceilings, i.e. the local masses inside the system.

C: All particles are attracted towards the center of mass of the building as a whole, i.e. the global center of gravity.

D: The dust moves towards the densest single mass inside the building.

E(mistyped as another C in image below): Something else.

[image]

Any answers for the real scenario and its underlying principles would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A is not correct. Gravitational forces inside the building will not cancel out, except in a few specific locations - and even those locations will not be stable equilibrium points.

C is not correct. The concept of centre of mass is only relevant for calculating gravitational forces on objects outside of the building - and even then, only if the building's design is symmetric.

So you are left with a combination of B and D. Dust close to walls an ceilings will be gravitationally attracted to the nearest surface. Dust floating in the centre of a room will be gravitationally attracted towards the large mass concentration.

This is like our solar system. For objects near to or on the surface of a planet, the most significant gravitational attraction acting on them is the planet. For objects in outer space, not close to a planet, the most significant gravitational attraction acting on them is the Sun, which contains more than 99% of the mass in the solar system.

Comment: Thank you for a clear answer. To generalize scenario C: would it be true to say that in no system can an empty point of space (i.e. the massless theoretical center of mass for the system)  be the point of gravitational attraction, so that a particle would settle there happily?

Comment: @erikm There are exceptions for very symmetric shapes. For example, inside a perfectly symmetric spherical shell the gravitational attraction from all points of the shell cancels out and the net gravitational field strength is zero. But inside a general, asymmetric shape that will not happen.